# MongoDB 3-level aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Suppose we have a list of schools so that each school is assigned city, state (province) and country.

Is it possible to build an aggregated list of unique cities/states/countries with MongoDB aggregation framework?

What I have:

```
[
{
    "School_name” : "School #1",
    "state" : "CA"
    "city” : "San-Francisco",
    "country” : "USA",
},
{
    "School_name” : "School #2",
    "state" : "CA"
    "city” : "San-Francisco",
    "country” : "USA",
},
{
    "School_name” : "School #3",
    "state" : "CA"
    "city” : "Los Angeles",
    "country” : "USA",
},
{
    "School_name” : "School #4",
    "state" : "CO"
    "city” : "Denver",
    "country” : "USA",
},
{
    "School_name” : "School #5",
    "state" : "CO"
    "city” : "Boulder",
    "country” : "USA",
},
{
    "School_name” : "School #6",
    "state" : "Hessen"
    "city” : "Frankfurt",
    "country” : "Germany",
}
```

]

What I need to get:

```
[
{
 "country" : "Germany",
     "states" :  
  [     
      {
    "state" : "Hessen",
        "cities" : [Frankfurt,...]
      }
      ]
},
{
 "country" : "USA",
     "states" :  
      [
    {
    "state" : "CA",
        "cities" : [San-Francisco, Los Angeles, ...]
    }
    {
    "state" : "CO",
        "cities" : [Boulder, Denver, ...]
    }
      ]
},
```

]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keeping the stages simple. And no need to `$addToSet` since the top level group sorts out duplicates:

```js
db.school.aggregate([{
    $group: { 
        _id: { 
            country: "$country",
            state: "$state", 
            city: "$city" 
        }
    }},
   {$group: { 
       _id: { 
       country: "$_id.country",
       state: "$_id.state" },
       cities: {$push: "$_id.city"} }
   },
   {$group: { 
       _id: "$_id.country",
       states: {$push: { state: "$_id.state", cities: "$cities" }} 
   }},
   {$project: { _id: 0, country: "$_id", states: "$states" }}
])
```

So it is actually a three group stage aggregation

Comment: I was able to achieve the same result with one fewer $group phase.

Comment: @AnandJayabalan It's still 4 stages and the last is arguably not needed. Different approach but actually the non **set** operation will perform better in a larger dataset.

Comment: the group phase is performance intensive. For large data sets, an aggregation query with 2 group phases will perform better than another with 3 group phases.  The project phases doesn't impact the performance as much (IMHO).

Comment: @AnandJayabalan Understand that the **first** phase does all the work necessary. There are reduced results coming out of additional stages. The general uniqueness in grouping is less costly than the additional checks to uniqueness introduced by $addToSet. Also $group is further optimized in 2.6, where a $project will force a pass through all of the results without much other operation.

Comment: You are right.  I agree, your approach is better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$group:{_id:{country:"$country", state:"$state"}, cities:{$addToSet:"$city"}}}, 
{$project:{country:"$_id.country", state:"$_id.state", cities:1, _id:0}}, 
{$group:{_id:"$country", states:{$push:{state:"$state", cities:"$cities"}}}}
{$project:{country:"$_id",states:1, _id:0}}
])
```

Comment: There is no need to add the extra projection. $group does exactly the same thing.

Comment: I added the intermediate project just to simplify the references in the second group phase.  I agree it isn't required.