# Aggregate by country, state and city

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, database

Suppose we have a list of companies so that each company is assigned city, state (province) and country.

I'm looking for a solution, to create a **3-level aggregation** as [already mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225420/mongodb-3-level-aggregation). Unfortunately, I am not able to translate the raw MongoDB query to PHP.

Current exception:

```
exception: invalid operator '$push'
```

Database Item:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52c85fafc8526a4d0d21e0be"),
    "city" : "Freiburg",
    "country" : "DE",
    "state" : "DE-BW",
    "_coords" : {
        "latitude" : 47.9990077,
        "longitude" : 7.842104299999999
    }
}
```

Source:

```
$collection = $this->getClient()->getCollection('companies');

$ops = array(
    array(
    '$group' => array(
        '_id' => array(
        'country' => '$country',
        'state' => '$state', 
        'city' => '$city' 
        ),
    ),
    ),
    array(
    '$group' => array(
        '_id' => array(
        'country' => '$_id.country',
        'state' => '$_id.state'
        ),
    ),
    ),
    array(
    '$group' => array(
        '_id' => array(
        'country' => '$_id.country',
        'state' => array('$push' => '$_id.state')
        ),
    ),
    ),
    array(
    '$sort' => array(
        'state' => 1
    ),
    )
);

$results = $collection->aggregate($ops);
```

Expected result:

```
[
    {
    "country" : "DE",
        "states" :  
        [     
            {
                "state" : "DE-BW",
                "cities" : [
                    {
                        "city": "Freiburg",
                        "_coords": {
                            "latitude" : 47.9990077,
                            "longitude" : 7.842104299999999
                        }
                    },

                    ...

                ]
            },

            ...

          ]
    },

    ...

]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want **two** [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) levels here. Optionally using [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) rather than [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) for uniqueness:

In basic JSON notation for the rest of the people:

```js
db.country.aggregate([
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": {
            "country": "$country",
            "state": "$state"
        },
        "cities": { 
            "$addToSet": {
                "city": "$city",
                "_coords": "$_coords"
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id.country",
        "states": {
            "$addToSet": {
                "state": "$_id.state",
                "cities": "$cities"
            }
        }
    }}       
])
```

And in PHP notation for you:

```
$collection->aggregate(
    array(
        array(
            '$group' => array(
                 '_id' => array(
                     'country' => 'country',
                     'state' => '$state'
                 ),
                 '$cities' => array(
                     '$addToSet' => array(
                         'city' => '$city',
                         '_coords' => '$_coords'
                      )
                 )
            )
        ),
        array(
            '$group' => array(
                '_id' => '$_id.country',
                'states' => array(
                    '$addToSet' => array(
                         'state' => '$_id.state',
                         'cities' => '$cities'                                  
                     )              
                )              
            )
        )
    )
);
```

But seriously, learn how to use `json_decode`. JSON is pretty much the "lingua franca" for general data structure representation, not to detract from YAML or simplified XML or others. It really is not hard to translate these things into a native language representation, especially when many libraies exist to do so.