# How to do a multi-stage nested aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I currently have a database with a collection called `people`.

Each document includes the following properties: `city`, `state`, and `country`.

Example:

```
{
    "_id": "5cd80e1ab3ee820fd9416301",
    "name": "John Doe",
    "city": "New York City",
    "state": "NY",
    "country": "US"
}
```

What I'm trying to do is get an array of people in each city, in each state, in each country.

Example:

```
{
    "US": {
        "NY": {
            "New York City": [
                {
                    "_id": "5cd80e1ab3ee820fd9416301",
                    "name": "John Doe"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22226355/11494525), which is close, but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

Comment: This may help you,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54088312/how-to-select-only-matched-sub-document-of-mongodb-using-python/54125182#54125182

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
db.people.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                country: "$country",
                state: "$state",
                city: "$city",
                person: "$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                country: "$_id.country",
                state: "$_id.state",
                city: "$_id.city",
                person: "$_id.person"
            },
            people: {
                $push: "$_id.person"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                country: "$_id.country",
                state: "$_id.state"
            },
            cities: {
                $push: {
                    city: "$_id.city",
                    people: "$people"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                country: "$_id.country"
            },
            states: {
                $push: {
                    state: "$_id.state",
                    cities: "$cities"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            country: "$_id.country",
            states: "$states"
        }
    }
]);
```

The result will look like this:

```
{
    "country": "US",
    "states": [ 
        {
            "state": "NY",
            "cities": [ 
                {
                    "city": "New York City",
                    "people": [ 
                        {
                            "_id": "5cd80e1ab3ee820fd9416301",
                            "name": "John Doe",
                            "city": "New York City",
                            "state": "NY",
                            "country": "US"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```